Permittivity from a quantum perspective
"The exchange of a virtual photon between two electrons causes each to experience a momentum 'kick' that is viewed as the electromagnetic force between them." Keeping this in mind, would it be fair to say that the reason permittivity has different values in different mediums is because these "virtual photons" would have different speeds in various materials, as the medium would slow down these particles (although virtual) and would allow less transmission of the Coloumbic force.
I apologize if it sounds stupid. I am curious how the particle view of electrostatic force would be affected by different mediums.
